# Tracking usage by Tab in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, tabs

I have added a usage log tracking function to many of my Excel files (VBA code below).  These currently show which user opens a specific file and when they are opened.  However, I am trying to gather additional information.  Specifically, I am looking for a way to record which tabs a user navigates to (in addition to the fact that they opened the file).  The primary goal of this is to eliminate work that results from creating exhibits on tabs that are not regularly referenced.

This is the code I am currently using to create a generic usage log to see who opens the file (and when);

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Usage.log" For Append As #2
    Print #2, Application.UserName, Now
    Close #2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This set of sub procedures in the ThisWorkbook code sheet should cover most scenarios.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Usage.log" For Append As #2
    Print #2, Application.UserName, Now & " open"
    Print #2, Application.UserName, Now, ActiveSheet.Name & " activate"
    Close #2

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Usage.log" For Append As #2
    Print #2, Application.UserName, Now & " close"
    Close #2

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Usage.log" For Append As #2
    Print #2, Application.UserName, Now, Sh.Name & " activate"
    Close #2

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Usage.log" For Append As #2
    Print #2, Application.UserName, Now, Sh.Name & " deactivate"
    Close #2

End Sub
```